# Updating encrypted JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to update my encrypted JSON but I'm getting a "NotSupportedException: Memory stream is not expandable" below is my code

```
public void SetLevelData(GameLevel value) 
{
    var newContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

    var jsonByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newContent);

    using MemoryStream decryptionStream = new MemoryStream(jsonByte);

    using Aes aesProvider = Aes.Create();
    aesProvider.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
    aesProvider.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(IV);

    using ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = aesProvider.CreateEncryptor();

    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
        decryptionStream,
        cryptoTransform,
        CryptoStreamMode.Write
        );

   cryptoStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newContent));
    }
```

GameLevel is a class

```
public class GameLevel
{
    public int NextLevelToUnlock { get; set; }
    public List<LevelDetails> LevelDetails { get; set; }

    public GameLevel() { }

    public GameLevel(int nextLevelToUnlock, List<LevelDetails> levelDetails)
    {
        NextLevelToUnlock = nextLevelToUnlock;
        LevelDetails = levelDetails;
    }
}

public class LevelDetails
{
    public int LevelIndex { get; set; }
    public int Stars { get; set; }

    public LevelDetails(int levelIndex, int stars)
    {
        LevelIndex = levelIndex;
        Stars = stars;
    }
}

public static class GameLevelBuilder
{
    public static GameLevel GameLevelWithDefaultValue()
    {
        var defaultLevelDetail = new List<LevelDetails>()
        {
            new LevelDetails(1, 0),
            new LevelDetails(2, 0),
            new LevelDetails(3, 0)
        };

        return new GameLevel(1, defaultLevelDetail);
    }
}
```

Update 2:
Sorry got confused. I just overwrite the old file below is my code:

```
public void SetLevelData(GameLevel value) 
    {
        var newContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

        using FileStream stream = File.Create(GetJSONPath());

        using Aes aesProvider = Aes.Create();
        aesProvider.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
        aesProvider.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(IV);

        using ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = aesProvider.CreateEncryptor();

        using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
            stream,
            cryptoTransform,
            CryptoStreamMode.Write
            );

        cryptoStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newContent));
    }
```

Comment: And where is defined GameLevelBuilder?

Comment: You're writing to the decryption stream, which already contains `jsonByte`.  Why are you doing that?  Do you want both the unencrypted and encrypted content in the stream?  If you only want the encrypted content, do `using MemoryStream decryptionStream = new MemoryStream()` and the stream will be writable and resizable.  (And you should probably also rename it to `encryptedStream`.)

Comment: I'm really confused about what you are doing here. Are you encrypting or decrypting? And what do you want to do with the result? If you are only encrypting why is your variable called `decryptionStream`?

Comment: *Update 2: Sorry got confused. I just overwrite the old file below is my code:* -- does this mean you have resolved your own problem?